# Reactjs reusable components using same data and onclick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement reusable component where data will be removed on the click function of the specific component.

But on click of one components removes the other component's data since I am using same data for reusable components. Is there a better way to do this?

my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ShotList from "./List"

function App() {
  const [data,setData] = React.useState([
    {
      name1:"asdsad",
      key: 0
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 1
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 2
    }
  ]);

  const removeData = (index) => {
    setData(data.filter((value) => value.key !== index))
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShotList data={data} removeData={removeData}></ShotList>
      <ShotList data={data} removeData={removeData}></ShotList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my list.js file

```
import React from "react";

const ShotList = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  return (
    <>
      {data.data.map((value,key) => (
        <p onClick={() => {console.log(key);data.removeData(key)}} key={key}>{value.name1}</p>
      ))}
      <p>123</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShotList;
```

Comment: Please check my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be as follows:

- Once you pass data to the child components, mantain them as local state then clear the data on that components local state. i.e

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ShotList from "./List"

function App() {
  const [data,setData] = React.useState([
    {
      name1:"asdsad",
      key: 0
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 1
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 2
    }
  ]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShotList data={data}></ShotList>
      <ShotList data={data}></ShotList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On the child/Shortlist Component:

```
import React from "react";

const ShotList = (data) => {
  const [localData, setLocalData] = useState(data)

 const removeData = (index) => {
    setLocalData(localData.filter((value) => value.key !== index))
  }


  return (
    <>
      {localData.map((value,key) => (
        <p onClick={() => {console.log(key);removeData(key)}} key={key}>{value.name1}</p>
      ))}
      <p>123</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default ShotList;
```

Comment: Duplicating parent state is an anti-pattern which ought to be avoided. What if parent data changes? Now you have to merge it with local changes inside a `useEffect`. You should always try to have a single source of truth for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make this line twice:

```
<ShotList data={data} removeData={removeData}></ShotList>
<ShotList data={data} removeData={removeData}></ShotList>
```

because it will render your `data` twice and because of that elements inside `.map` would have the same `key` so removing one of them will remove also all that have the same `key` value.

If you want to have more elements just add new ones inside `data` state like:

```
const [data,setData] = React.useState([
    {
      name1:"asdsad",
      key: 0
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 1
    },
    {
      name1:"asdrsad",
      key: 2
    },
    {
      name1:"new one",
      key: 3
    },
    {
      name1:"fourth one",
      key: 4
    },
    {
      name1:"fifth one",
      key: 5
    }
 ]);
```